# Ignore facebook errors and continue script

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Sometimes my script gets errors like this: 
`(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist`.

How it's possible to make my script to ignore this error and continue to get data ?

CODE:

```
public function getClub($id) 
{
    $session = $this->fbStart();
    $GET = '?fields=about,category,company_overview,cover,founded,likes,link,location,name,phone,username,website';
    return (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$id.$GET.''))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className())->asArray();
}

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $club = $model->getClub($id);
    $model->saveClub($club);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code example that shows how/what you are sending?

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, let's say it could be this: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/244933134010`. I wish to not see error if link would be `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/24493313401`. And continue script to fetch data from other links (ids)

Comment: Show your code (presumably a loop?). It's hard to point you in the right direction without seeing how you are doing your fetching data portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated code, you likely need just put an if/else in there.

EDIT: You are using the method chain version, break it into the non-chained version. Then you can work with exceptions and returned errors using if/else. This is from FB SDK documentation:

```
try {
      $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute();
      $object = $response->getGraphObject();
      // Here is likely where you will get the error back, though I am guessing,
      // I have never used their SDK...
      echo $object->getProperty('name');
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
      // Or here is where the message will come back
      echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/4.0.0

Comment: Nope, the error is thrown in getClub function, then ID is not found.

Comment: Yeah, that is fine. The error is returned into the `$club` variable, correct?

Comment: No, it's happens before. In getClub function.

Comment: Ok, so I think you need to use the long version of the FB request class instead of the method chain you are using now.

Comment: No problem. I think this method will work because it breaks down the call into separate pieces where you can return false back to your loop thus stopping any further action using the `$model->saveClub($club)` on errored returns. Anyway, you will have to fiddle, I'm sure, but I think you'll get it working like you want! Cheers